# How to create advanced custom action bar in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want to create my own action bar (as you can see ).

[image]

It is a bit advanced, that is why I can not find ready solution on the internet. I want to create two-coloured bar (on the left green with text, on the right grey with button) 
I am using

```
@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

with

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: IMHO, that's not an action bar. Just get rid of the action bar from your activity and put those views at the top of your layout.

Comment: Any app with a Custom ActionBar like that is not "simple" because it requires you to code your own animations on it